# C++ parameterized constructor In a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I recently start learning templates in C++ and I am not sure if I need to include `template <class T>`for my implementation of a parameterized constructor.

```
  template <class T>
  class A
  {    T num;

    //default constructor (parameterized)

    template <class T>//getting error
    A(T value)
    { num=value;}
  }
```

I get an error shadow template parm < class T > when I include `template<class T>` for the constructor.But it works when I comment it out.

I am wondering why I dont need to declare the template for the constructor.

Comment: Change `<T>num;` to `T num;` and remove `template <class T>` before the constructor definition.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? and the problem is in this line `<T>num` and `template <class T>` you can change the same

Comment: For the nested templating you need new unique template parameter names. Whether you need templating for the constructor or not depends on what you want it do.

Comment: @yanivs shadow template parm <class T>

Comment: @Cheers and hth what are the occasions when you need to template the constructor?

Comment: @Lzy: I can give you an example. `std::shared_ptr` is a class template with a templated constructor. The idea is that shared_ptr instances should convert implicitly just like raw pointers. In particular, a `shared_ptr<Derived>` can be accepted by the templated constructor of a `shared_ptr<Base>`. Se constructor overload 9 in [the list over at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure you need a templated constructor function, then use a different parameter name for the template:

```
template <class T>
  class A
  {   
    T num;

    //default constructor (parameterized)

    template <class U>
                 // ^
    A(U value)
   // ^
    { num=value;}
  };
```

Otherwise the template parameter name `T` used for the templated constructor function would shadow the name used in the class template declaration.

---

As you are asking in a comment *"What are the occasions to use a templated constructor?"*

It's for cases like

```
A<double> a(0.1f);
```

Note the above is just a simple example, and wouldn't need a templated constructor. It's just to demonstrate the templated constructor is used for conversion from types that are different from the type used in the instantiation.

---

> *"I am wondering why I dont need to declare the template for the constructor."*

A template class without (or with an additional) non-templated constructor would simply use the `T` specified as class template parameter for the parameter type

```
template <class T>
  class A
  {   
    T num;

    A(T value)
   // ^
    { num=value;}
  };
```

This is the standard case, most template classes don't need templated constructor or other templated functions.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the <T> num part. But when should I use a templated constructor, or what is the difference between a regular constructor and a templated one?

Comment: You should use a template for a constructor when you do not want the default constructor to be called. Besides If you declare any constructor(including a templated one), the compiler will refrain from declaring a default constructor

Comment: so if the value I want to put in is `double`in the example you provided, I dont need  a templated constructor?

Comment: @Lzy Because conversion from `float` to `double` would work automatically. If you have something like `A<Base> a(Derived())` you'll need it.

Comment: what would happen if I have two declarations, one with template and one without and I want to call the constructor in the templated class?

Comment: @Lzy If you have a second non-templated version, it will be used with the type that is used for instantiation of the template class.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ Sorry I am still quite new to this and I dont get how the non-templated version works...can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Lzy Updated my answer. I hope it's getting clearer for you now.